# srandom( time( NULL ) )

Tags: c, random

May I know the meaning or even how to read this:

```
srandom( time( NULL ) )?
```

Comment: You initialize a random() function with a seed. In this case the seed is the current time.

Comment: It could mean anything, as there is no function called "srandom" in the C language. (I believe it is a POSIX function?) The standard function is called `srand`.

Answer (score 32):

```
NULL
```

A null pointer. Zero. Points to nothing.

```
time(NULL)
```

The [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function returns the current timestamp as an integer. It accepts an input argument. If the argument is not null, the current time is stored in it.

```
srandom(time(NULL))
```

The `s` means "seed". [`srandom`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/srandom.3.html) means "seed the random number generator". It takes an integer as input, reset the PRNG's internal state derived by the input to generate a sequence of random numbers according to it. The seed is sometimes used to ensure 2 sequences of random numbers are the same, to reproduce an equivalent testing condition.

In general, you just put some always changing value there to avoid having the same sequence every time the program is started. The current timestamp is a good value, so `time(NULL)` is used as the input.

Comment: Whether seeding based on time is a good idea depends on the application - though probably only security types would seriously disaprove, and they wouldn't be using standard library random numbers anyway I guess.

Comment: time() always returns the current time. If the argument is not NULL, the current time will be stored in that pointer too. Since it's always returned anyway, the time(NULL) form is quite common. Good explanation though :)

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is to initialize the random seed with the current time.
time(NULL) returns the current time. srandom() initializes random seed.

Answer (score 3):

`srandom` is a function that initializes the random number generator.

It takes a seed value, which in this code is `time(NULL)`, which is the current time.

This is read, "srandom *of* time *of* null".